# Sumo Logic search query

Tags: sumo

I am new to Sumo Logic but hoping someone can help!
this is the part of the search query giving me grief

```
| keyvalue "svname", "lastchg", "status"
| num(lastchg) #lastchg is a keyvalue 
| keyvalue "svname", "lastchg", "status"
```

but even running just running

```
| num(lastchg) or | num(lastchg) as upTime
```

I get an error "For input string: "NULL"" How do I get rid of it

Abbey

Answer (score 1):

You can try running

```
keyvalue "svname", "lastchg", "status" 
where !isNull(lastchg) 
num(lastchg)
```

to fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

You can't pass a null value to the built-in operator num(). This is why you get the error.

This is the rule for this operator: *The value of the field must be a negative/positive integer or a real number. For example, 500, 123234820932, or 352.748.*

You can use where operator to filter null values for lastchg as suggested by Andronicus. Or you can set a default value of 0 for null by using if operator as below.

| if(isNull(lastchg), 0, lastchg) as lastchg